# Constrained smooth transition between points.

Tags: functions, physics, problem-solving, word-problem, smooth-functions

Since I'm not very skilled at math, I'll try to explain my problem with apples.

At a certain train station, every train driver has a specific route to cover everyday.

A pair of brothers, who happen to work at the same station with the same schedule, both have been assigned a route next to each other, and so, they're able to talk along the way without any radio interference, given how close they are to each other.

[image: Ideal case]

One day, after one of them got assigned a new route, they began having trouble to communicate; since they were not moving at the same pace anymore, the increasing distance between them started to produce transmission issues; and so, our problem begins.

[image: What to do?]

- If the two brothers stay at the same pace, they won't be able to finish their routes at the same time. ['A' & 'B']
- Even if both move at the same relative speed, lets say, 1% per second, eventually they'll end up shifting away, since `(1% of 10) != (1% of 6.4)` ['A' & 'C']

Is there any way to accomplish the following objectives at the same time:

- Both trains must complete their routes, as usual.
- Both trains should stay as close/aligned as possible along their way, to improve radio communications.
- After all, it doesn't matter if they end up shifting away: It's all about maximizing how much time they move along and/or minimizing their relative displacement from each other.

Additionally, we need to consider the following:

- There are no speed limits.
- Both trains have same length.
- Tracks are static, so moving them to reduce gap between trains isn't possible.
- Focus must stay on the trains. (Ignore the radio frequency/power, schedules, weather, fuel, etc...)
- Both trains must:

  - Start at the same time.
  - Finish at the same time.
  - Start from the same point.

Optionally, these would be desired:

- A way to solve this with N trains.
- Any speed compensation should start from the beginning, smoothly increasing towards its maximum.
- Solution(s) should avoid functions whose behavior looks very sharp at first glance, until you «zoom» enough on it, like a «microscopic» curve.
- In other words, there needs to exist some kind of limit into how smooth a function can be, be it a speed, acceleration or jolt limit.

[image: Needle at microscope]

"Microscopic view of a bee sting (sharper) vs a needle tip (rounder)". *Source: Twitter.com / @microscopicture*

---

Given the above, the ideal answer would look like this:
[image: What if...?]

Where both trains start & stay at the same pace, just as if both of them had to cover up the same distance (Fulfills objective #2), just for one of them to «teleport» the very instant any of the trains reach their destination by conventional means (Fulfills objective #1); while effectively solving our problem, such approach isn't smooth at all, which would be desired, if possible.

Resulting behavior should look like this:

[image: Manual]

---

Just by using common sense, my logic tells me that there must be a relationship between the «absolute difference between route lengths» & the «speed compensation». That is, the bigger the difference, the faster one train might need to go.

Particularly, I feel like this might be solvable by using a custom smoothness variable/factor, but I was wondering if there could be a more «natural» way to do it; that is, only using information provided by the problem itself, like the above.

If there's not, maybe using e, pi, phi or some irrational number/function for such custom variable might do the trick.

---

EDIT: Despite the `problem-solving` tag, I'm actually looking for a concrete solution/example to this, but I'd greatly appreciate any kind of help, including guidance on this; hence, the tag.

Comment: See the notion of a bump function. Try to modify the teleporting solution to a smooth solution where they stop being perfectly in pace with each other only when the shorter track has $\epsilon$ left to go. The lack of limits on speed, acceleration etc mean you can do a lot while still remaining "smooth"

Comment: Many thanks for replying: When I first tried to solve this myself, I eventually stumbled upon the bump function; unfortunately, I understand very little of it, at least from its Wikipedia article. That being said, seeing an example, or a much more simple article on it, would greatly help me.

Comment: Besides, while it's true there are no smoothness limits on the problem itself, it'd be desirable to solve it using the bare minimum smoothness degree possible; I've just edited my question accordingly.

Hopefully I'm explaining myself the right way.

Comment: You have the ordering on smoothness vs the number on the superscript the wrong way around. The lower the "C grade", the less restrictive and more crazy you can get. You can be more restrictive by going $C^\omega$ or by imposing some speed,acceleration,etc limits. Not by lowering the "C grade"

Comment: Oh wow, seems I got it all wrong then: Thank you for your patience explaining this to me in simple terms. I might need to edit my question once more. So, let me get this straight: You're suggesting me to impose some kind of [speed | accel | jolt] limit, in order to avoid getting a function with a «microscopic» smooth curve, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use your *ideal solution* as the starting point. Your *ideal solution* is a piecewise function $s: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ where
$$s(t) = \begin{cases}
6.4 t \text{ if } 0 \le t < 1 \\
10 \text{ if } t = 1
\end{cases}$$
Graphically, it looks like [image: Figure 1]

Obviously, $s(t)$ is non-smooth because it is discontinuous at $t = 1$ (the train teleports at $t = 1$).

---

To fix this problematic jump, we can smooth out the function using a smooth transition function. Our method is very similar to the one mentioned in [Smooth Bump Function Between Two Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3817438/smooth-bump-function-between-two-functions), but I feel like it is easier to use the smooth transition function defined in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#Smooth_transition_functions).

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by
$$f(t) =
\begin{cases}
0 \text{ if } t \le 0 \\
e^{-\frac{1}{t}} \text{ if } t > 0
\end{cases}$$
Then $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$g(t) = \frac{f(t)}{f(t) + f(1 - t)}$$ is smooth transition function from $0$ to $1$ in the sense that

1. $g(t)$ is smooth ($g(t)$ is infinitely differentiable)
2. $g(t) = 0$ for all $t \le 0$
3. $g(t) = 1$ for all $t \ge 1$

The proof can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#Smooth_transition_functions). Graphically, it looks like [image: Figure 2]

We can now use it to define what we want. Fix $\varepsilon$ with $0 < \varepsilon < \frac{1}{2}$ and let $s_\varepsilon: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $$s_\varepsilon(t) = 6.4 t + 3.6 g\left(\frac{t - (1 - \varepsilon)}{\varepsilon}\right)$$
Then $s_\varepsilon(t)$ is a smooth function because sum of smooth functions is smooth and smoothness is preserved by re-scaling and shifting. Graphically, it looks like [image: Figure 3]

Notice the corners have been smoothened, which is what we want.

Here $\varepsilon$ can be thought of as the "sharpness" parameter. The smaller $\varepsilon$ is, the "sharper" the function $s_\varepsilon(t)$ is and the closer it is to $s(t)$. In fact, $$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} s_\varepsilon(t) = s(t)$$

Graphically, it looks like [image: Figure 4]

---

Finally, to get a formula for $s_\varepsilon(t)$, observe that $f(t) = e^{-\frac{1}{t}} \theta(t, 0)$ where $\theta(t, t_0)$ is the Heaviside step function defined by $$\theta(t, t_0) =
\begin{cases}
0 \text{ if } t < 0 \\
t_0 \text{ if } t = 0 \\
1 \text{ if } t > 0
\end{cases}$$
Hence $$s_\varepsilon(t) = 6.4 t + 3.6 g\left(\frac{t - (1 - \varepsilon)}{\varepsilon}\right) \\
= 6.4 t + 3.6 \frac{e^{\frac{\varepsilon}{(1 - \varepsilon) - t}} \theta\left(\frac{t - (1 - \varepsilon)}{\varepsilon}, 0\right)}{e^{\frac{\varepsilon}{(1 - \varepsilon) - t}} \theta\left(\frac{t - (1 - \varepsilon)}{\varepsilon}, 0\right) + e^{\frac{\varepsilon}{t - 1}} \theta\left(\frac{1 - t}{\varepsilon}, 0\right)}$$
is the desired formula.